# Downloading part of a web page - data mining

Tags: c#, php, http, data-mining

this is basically what I'm doing. I select a science article from en.wikipedia.org and get the a list of users that have made edits and how many times they've edited the article. To get this I follow links from the page to get that lead me to toolserver. I use this page http://toolserver.org/~daniel/WikiSense/Contributors.php?wikilang=en&wikifam=.wikipedia.org&page=Quantum_mechanics&since=&until=&grouped=on&hideanons=on&order=-edit_count&max=100&order=-edit_count&format=wiki to retrieve the editors in a sorted list and excluding anonymous. This works well, because it comes in a nicely formatted list, (even though it has dates which I don't need).

However, to judge their credibility, I need to take a look at the top users and see the top articles they're contributing to, to see if they're editing a lot of science articles or just random junk. I'm having a hard time getting data on each of these users, as currently, the only site I can find that shows user history is http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Contributions&limit=5000&target=Aquirata

However, it takes quite a while to get a single user's webpage, at least 20 seconds, and then I still have to parse out the useless data, etc. I don't need close to as much data as I'm forced to download. This is my code so far for getting a user's data:

```
    static string getWebPage(string url)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers.Add("user-agent",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.9.2.4) Gecko/20100611 Firefox/3.6.4");

        return client.DownloadString(url);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Contributions&limit=50&target=Aquirata";

        string page = getWebPage(url);
        var lines = page.Split('\n', '\r');
        var edits = lines.Where(t => t.StartsWith("<li class"));
        foreach (string s in edits)
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Is there a possible alternative that will be faster and/or easier? Maybe there's a database somewhere for this? (i'm not sure if wikimedia has statistics on user's contributions).

Also, I'm using C# because I'm most familiar with it. I might switch over to java to allow cross platform but I'm open for any other suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting only a certain part of a document can be done with a range request, which are documented in [RFC 2616 Section 14.16](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.16).

For example:

```
$ curl -H"range: bytes=1-20" www.apache.org
!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC
$
```

Answer (score 8):

I think wikipedia provides their data for download (so you don't have to strip it out from the HTML page).

See: http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can Deal with the WIKI as XML so you can use XPATHs to get the required data.